# DTD Error in Oxygen but not in Netbeans so confused

Tags: xml, netbeans, dtd, oxygenxml

I am trying to create an XML file with a DTD, but in Netbeans it doesn't give me any errors, but in Oxygen XML it states 
**Unexpected element "childone". The content of the parent element type must match "((c:childone,c:childtwo)|(childone,childtwo,childthree,childfour))".**

The XML I have is as follows:

```
<rootelement>
   <c:childone></c:childone>
   <c:childtwo></c:childtwo>
   <childone></childone>
   <childtwo></childtwo>
   <childthree></childthree>
   <childfour></childfour>
</rootelement>
```

The DTD I have as follows:

```
<!ELEMENT rootelement ((c:childone,c:childtwo)|(childone,childtwo,childthree,childfour))>
<!ELEMENT c:childone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT c:childtwo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT childone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT childtwo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT childthree (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT childfour (#PCDATA)>
```

I'm confused now, please help. Hope I formatted this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTD says the contents of `<rootelement>` can be one of two forms; your actual document contains both of them. Pick one, or change the DTD.

I suspect Netbeans is simply not validating, and hence is not noticing the problem.

By the way, DTDs are VERY poorly suited to working with namespaced documents -- and I certainly hope you've bound the `c:` prefix to a namespace! -- so I'd strongly recommend switching to XML Schemas, which are a more powerful replacement for DTDs.

Comment: I am actually creating a DTD and schema. But I'm creating the DTD first then the schema. The c: is a prefix to a namespace. I'm still learning. I thought I could have an "or" to select either the ones with the prefix of the c or the ones without in the DTD, but obviously not.

Comment: The or is between two different sets of content. As you've written it, you can have one set (prefixed) or the other set (non-prefixed) but not both. If you wan to allow a mix, the grammar has to say so.

Unless you have a very specific reason for dealing with them, these days I'd skip DTDs.

Comment: Ah I see so technically my DTD must be changed ot I must remove one of the group of elements, either the preceding ones or the ones that don't precede.